# Adjust deraillers after changing chain?

Tags: chain, derailleur, adjustment

I just changed the chain on my Cube Acid 2X11sp  mtb. I replaced the old chain with an exactly similar brand, model and length new chain (shimano). Is it NECESSARY to readjust and finetune the speed changing mechanisms (deraillers)?

Comment: In theory no adjustment is required. In practice going to the cost and effort of a new chain without checking the derailleur is shifting optimally is a waste.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replacing a chain on a drivetrain that was previously well tuned will not take it out of alignment. Provided that the new chain is the same width and number of links as the old one and that the cassette and chainring aren't worn, no further work is required.

Comment: I agree, but derailleurs probably could use some attention, or at lest just checking when chain changed.

Comment: Changing a chain is always a good opportunity for testing the smoothness of the gear changing and a check of the shifting cables as well.